# how do i install libraries not on npm using browserify?

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs, npm, browserify

I've been working with angular and using bower as a package manager. For a current project I want to use some npm modules in the browser and started with browserify

For my starter project I was able to `npm install angular angular-ui-router --save` because they have [npm](https://www.npmjs.org/package/angular-ui-router) [packages](https://www.npmjs.org/package/angular) but I'm used to installing dependencies with `bower install`

Building my browserify-angular app, how do I install dependencies that aren't listed on npm? Essentially does browserify have a replacement to `bower install`, or could I use bower with browserify?

For the current project I have a `package.json` looking like so:

```
{
  "name": "browserify-begin",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "dependencies": {
    "7digital-api": "^0.15.2",
    "angular": "^1.2.16",
    "angular-ui-router": "^0.2.10"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "browserify": "^4.1.5",
    "grunt": "^0.4.5",
    "grunt-browserify": "^2.1.0",
    "grunt-contrib-connect": "^0.7.1",
    "grunt-contrib-copy": "^0.5.0"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can install git-repos with npm [without them being published to npm](https://www.npmjs.org/doc/json.html#Git-URLs-as-Dependencies).

```
"dependencies": {
    "package": "git+https://github.com/path/to/repo#commitSHAhash"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to install via [debowerify](https://github.com/eugeneware/debowerify)

The package.json may then look as follows:

```
{
  "name": "browserify-begin",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "dependencies": {
    "7digital-api": "^0.15.2",
    "angular": "^1.2.16",
    "angular-ui-router": "^0.2.10"
  },
  "browserify": {
    "transform": [
      "debowerify"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "browserify": "^4.1.5",
    "debowerify": "^0.7.1",
    "grunt": "^0.4.5",
    "grunt-browserify": "^2.1.0",
    "grunt-contrib-connect": "^0.7.1",
    "grunt-contrib-copy": "^0.5.0"
  }
}
```

### Updates on 24-May-2014

Given the source javascript file is source.js
And you want to browserified to build.js

Using debowerify, if your source.js contains bower components like bootstrap etc, for example:

```
require('bootstrap')
```

The Gruntfile.js will look like the following:

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {

  // Project configuration.
  grunt.initConfig({
    // Metadata.
    pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),
    browserify: {
      bundleOptions: {
        debug: true
      },
      js: {
        src:['source.js'],
        dest: 'build.js'
      }
    }
  }),

  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-browserify');    
}
```

build.js will include bootstrap component

Comment: so do grunt-browserify and browserify work together? or should I just use the `$ browserify -t debowerify  public/scripts/app.js -o public/scripts/build/bundle.js` command when running my builds?

Comment: Hi @ConnorLeech the package.json as you see from here is used with grunt-browserify, I can post the Gruntfile.js section if you need a reference

Comment: that'd be awesome. i'm a noob